# Doctrine 2. Cannot create schema

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, doctrine, kohana

```
> php doctrine-cli.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Creating database schema...

[Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException]
  Schema-Tool failed with Error 'could not find driver' while executing DDL: CREATE TABLE comment (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, parentid INT NOT NULL,

I use this connecting options

```
       $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'interview2',
        'charset' => 'utf8'
    );
```

Doctrine has PDOMySql in Drivers directory. What is the problem? 
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have mysql extension in your php setup?

Comment: By looking in php.ini of the PHP installation in the extensions section. There you can see if the pdo extension is enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: I see this thing. I have pdo extension, but for php 5.3, but some time ago i compiled php 5.4 for me, so my pdo extension doesn't suit. Some people advised me to compile php once more with flag --with_pdo_mysql. Is it right way to solve problem? How can i do this?